# Format option not working when used inside an sql query python

Tags: python, string, postgresql, psycopg2

I have to write an sql query using the `.format` option in `python`. I am using the follwoing code which doesnt work as I expected.

```
alarm_tables = ["treevashialarm","treekhopolialarm","treetalegaonalarm"]
alarm_types = ['As%%','Sd%%','Multi%%']
```

Here is my query:

```
query_types = "SELECT \"alarmSeverity\", COUNT(*) FROM " + "'{0}'" + " WHERE isparent = true and eventdate+eventtime BETWEEN TIMESTAMP " + "'{1}" + "T18:30:00.000Z' " + " and TIMESTAMP " + "'{2}" + "T18:29:59.999Z' " + "and eventtype like '{3}' group by \"alarmSeverity\""
```

I am using the format option as below:

```
for i in alarm_tables:
    for j in alarm_types:
        query_types.format(i,'2019-10-01','2019-10-02',j)
        print(query_types)
```

I am getting an output as below :

```
SELECT "alarmSeverity", COUNT(*) FROM '{0}' WHERE isparent = true and eventdate+eventtime BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '{1}T18:30:00.000Z'  and TIMESTAMP '{2}T18:29:59.999Z' and eventtype like '{3}' group by "alarmSeverity"
```

My one of the Expected output is as below:

```
SELECT "alarmSeverity", COUNT(*) FROM treevashialarm WHERE isparent = true and eventdate+eventtime BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2019-10-09T18:30:00.000Z' AND TIMESTAMP '2019-10-10T18:29:59.999Z' and eventtype like 'As%' group by "alarmSeverity";
```

How can I get the desired `output`.Why is `format` not working.Is there a work around.The `for loop` doesnt work as well.It gives `random output` at random time.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`format()` doesn't modify the original string:

[image]

so if you want to do this you have to write:

```
query_types_formated = query_types.format(i,'2019-10-01','2019-10-02',j)
```

Comment: I tried that as well earlier,but for loop was not working :O weird eh? .Anyway now it works.Thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: @RAMSHANKERG I'm guessing you tried with query_types = query_types.format(...), so the first loop was okay but the second one broke because your query_types was not a formatable string anymore since you replaced it ?